# Can i click to dropdown the parallel stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I created a pipeline with parallel stages using Jenkins and BlueOcean to view the work flow.
Is there a way to view only the parallel stage and when clicked on dropdown all the stages inside?

In the example imagine I wanted that the stages inside the parallel stage (Browser tests) were hidden by default and when I clicked on it, they would appear like a dropdown menu for instance.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yKG5.png)

I searched everywhere and didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I have never seen such thing in Blue Ocean... That might be a good request to do for the future of the plugin. After checking the [Jira for the plugin](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-71560?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20component%20%3D%20blueocean-plugin), I didn't find such request.